# Unable to get response from Web api in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

Here is how I am returning data from WebAPI:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ProcessHistory")]
public HttpResponseMessage ProcessHistory()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    try
    {

        IProcessManagement ProcessManagement = serviceFactory.CreateProcessManagement();
        List<Process> listProcess = ProcessManagement.Get().ToList();
        response = Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<Process>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, listProcess);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Angular:

Angular Component method which calling to angular service:

```
getProcessScheduleStatus(){
  this.Service.getProcessScheduleStatus(this.ApiUrl + ConstAPIUrls.ProcessScheduleStatus).subscribe(
    (next: ProcessScheduleStatus[]) => {
      alert('Got status successfully..!!');
      console.log('Processes: ');
      console.log(next);
      this.result.IsSuccess = true;
      this.result.SuccessMessage = 'Success';
      this.openModal(this.result);
    },
    error => {
      alert('Error');
      if (error.status == 400) {
        this.result.IsSuccess = false;
        this.result.ErrorMessage = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error.error));
        this.openModal(this.result);
      }
      else {
        //Parse response for other error status
        this.result.IsSuccess = false;
        this.result.ErrorMessage = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error.message));
        this.openModal(this.result);
      }        
    },
    () => {
      //process to be run after web api request completes
    }
  );
}
```

Angular Service which is calling to Web api:

```
getProcessScheduleStatus(apiUrl: string):Observable<ProcessScheduleStatus[]>{
  return this._httpClient.get(apiUrl, this.httpOptions).map((result: ProcessScheduleStatus[]) => {
    alert('web api execued');
    if (result != null && result != undefined) {
      return result;
    }
    else {
      return result;
    }
  });
}
```

Here is the browser XHR result:
[image]

As Angular service hits to web api but when web api returns response it directly goes to components error handler.

How to read data from response appropriately?

Failure request header in chrome XHR:

[image]

Comment: Well what *is* the error? Why wouldn't it go to the error handler in the component, given that you don't handle it in the service? And why the `if` when you `return result;` whatever happens?

Comment: if you can please share the header info and response tab info from the chrome inspect, that way wil get more info

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it gives error as `Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error`

Comment: So what debugging have you tried? What *is* the URL you're making the request to? Are you sure that `this.ApiUrl` and `ConstAPIUrls.ProcessScheduleStatus` are both set and make sense when directly concatenated?

Comment: @Aji, as in screen first request gets executed and secord request throwing error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I had attached debugger in web api that hits web api 2 times. I search for why it hits 2 times then found first it check request type 'OPTION' then hits actual request with request type 'GET'. The first request executed successfully but error for second request.